# Copy and paste base on criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that will move all the cell base on a criteria to the right by one. For example. I need the macro to shift over 1,2,3 , Sunny, sunny, Cloudy to the right but only for the ones under day. I need to leave all the information under year intact. I need to repeat this for many lines,

```
Day#    Decription          Notes
1       Sunny               Bad
2       Sunny               Bad
3       Cloudy              Bad
Year    #   Decription
```

The ideal solution would be

```
Day #   Decription      Notes
    1   Sunny           Bad
    2   Sunny           Bad
    3   Cloudy          Bad
Year    #   Decription
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 2
Do until Cells(x,1) = "Year"
    Cells(x,4) = Cells(x,3)
    Cells(x,3) = ""
    Cells(x,2) = Cells(x,1)
    Cells(x,1) = ""
    x = x + 1
Loop
```

It should go without saying, but you'll need to modify the column and starting row numbers to suit your spreadsheet.  Try to give more detailed information in your questions in order to get more specific answers.

Comment: It should go without saying that we shouldn't be answering questions from people who show no effort or attempt at solving their own problems...